# Operaciones entre celdas con R

Tags: excel, r

Tengo varias columnas de índices macroeconómicos mensuales y me interesa obtener el  cambio porcentual entre cada mes, en Excel esto se hace con un par de clicks por ejemplo si en mi columna A tengo cronológicamente ordenado un índice específico lo haría con `(A2-A1)/A1` y luego con doble click lo aplicaría para el resto de la columna `(A3-A2)/A2, (A4-A3)/A3` etc. en R se me ocurre hacerlo como `(data$v1[2,]-data$v1[1,])/data$v1[1,]` pero ¿cómo traslado esta operación al resto de celdas de la columna?

Digamos que tenemos algo así en `Excel`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En R podría ser un `data.frame`como el siguiente:

```
df <- data.frame(A=1:6)
df
  A
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como has indicado, podemos acceder individualmente a cada celda para hacer algo como esto:

```
(df$A[2] - df$A[1]) / df$A[1]
```

Pero el inconveniente es que no se trata de una mecánica vectorizada, por lo que deberíamos iterar sobre cada fila, lo cual es posible si hacemos esto:

```
unlist(lapply(1:(nrow(df)-1), function(x) (df$A[x+1] - df$A[x]) / df$A[x]))
[1] 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000
```

Pero tenemos el problema que el vector final será de `n-1`, con lo cual habría que hacerlo homogeno con el original. Lo que suele ser más cómodo en estos casos, es generar un vector desplazado con la misma longitud del original, y entonces sí, podremos aplicar fácilmente la aritmética vectorial estándar de R. Hay muchas formas de desplazar un vector, en mi caso tengo está función:

```
shift <- function(x,k=1, na.value=NA) {
  stopifnot(abs(k) <= length(x))
  if (k==0) return(x)
  if (k>0) {
    c(rep(na.value,k),head(x,length(x)-k))
  } else {
    c(tail(x,length(x)+k), rep(na.value,abs(k)))
  }
}
```

Que permite, generar versiones desplazadas de cualquier vector, por ejemplo:

```
cbind(df$A,
     shift(df$A, -1),
     shift(df$A, -1, 0)
)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    2
[2,]    2    3    3
[3,]    3    4    4
[4,]    4    5    5
[5,]    5    6    6
[6,]    6   NA    0
```

Ahora, debería quedar mas clara la idea. con `shift(df$A, -1)` generamos un vector desplazado "hacia arriba" 1 posición, y agregamos `NA` a las posiciones vacías, con `shift(df$A, -1, 0)` hacemos lo mismo pero completamos con 0. Este último es el comportamiento del Excel (algo discutible). Y ahora sí:

```
df$NuevoA <- (shift(df$A,-1,0)-df$A)/df$A
df

  A     NuevoA
1 1  1.0000000
2 2  0.5000000
3 3  0.3333333
4 4  0.2500000
5 5  0.2000000
6 6 -1.0000000
```

Por último, si utilizaras `tidyverse/dplyr` tienes la posibilidad de usar la función `lead()/lag()` (ojo, no es `lag()` de R base) de esta forma:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(NuevoA= (lead(A, default = 0)-A)/A)
```

Comment: Genial, gracias.